# Event in Mysql that runs only on weekdays

Tags: mysql, events

I want to create an event in mysql that runs only on weekdays and inserts a row in a table. I am able to create a even that runs everyday or after n number of days but am unable to do what I intend to do. i.e. Event for weekdays only.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can run the event every day and just do nothing if it is not a weekday with an `if` condition

```
delimiter //
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS your_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
DO
    if DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) between 2 and 6 then
        Delete from attendance 
        where Att_mnth=Month(CurDate()) 
        and Att_day=DayOfMonth(CurDate());
    end if;
//
```

Comment: When I use the query in above mentioned format then I get the following error  <br/>  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DayOfWeek(curdate()) between 2 and 6 then (Delete from attendance where Att_m' at line 2

Comment: Tried it without () but no success

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DayOfWeek(curdate()) between 2 and 6 then Delete from attendance where Att_mnth' at line 2 –

Comment: Hard to tell without your complete query. Please add it.

Comment: The query that i am running is `Delete from attendance where Att_mnth=Month(CurDate()) and Att_day=DayOfMonth(CurDate());`

Answer (score 2):

You should make use of the `DAYOFWEEK(date)` MySQL function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek

If `DAYOFWEEK(date)` returns 7 or 1 (Saturday or Sunday) then you should skip the script.